# Is it necessary to take log transformation on the data values to get the minimum mean squared error?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I have tried the house price prediction problem using simple linear regression by using the square feet as independent variable and price as dependent variable.while trying to check the MSE of the model,I get the output as 61940787124.62475. But after taking the log transformation to both the variables,the model shows the MSE value as 0.14824951630518876. which method is correct?And since the first model gives the larger MSE value,does it means the first model is error prone?

Comment: Do you think that a Target in the range of 100K will have an error in the range of 0.2 even with a SOTA model. You will have to revert back the log Y to Y using exponential. Then calculate the error. But before everything else, check the assumption of LinearRegression, accordingly move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you applied the log transformation to all your labels as well as the inputs, then it is normal that the MSE decreases. It is the case because when you apply log to big numbers they all become smaller and less spread. The standard deviation of the log price is a lot smaller than the one of the price. The MSE of any model trying to predict the log price (for instance the model that predicts the mean log price every time) will be smaller than the MSE of a model trying to predict the price.

Using the log square footage to predict the price could be useful if you are using a linear regression for instance and if the relation between square footage and price were logarithmic. It is probably not the case but you can try it.

However changing the target (applying log to it) changes the loss (you are computing the MSE between log price and prediction) and thus changes the problem you are trying to solve. You cannot compare the performances of the two models directly using the outputed MSE.